# sql query on button click

Tags: php

i dont know whats wrong with my codes. kinda new to PHP

here is my html code

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="sample2.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="occupied" id="occupied">
<input type="submit" value="reserved" id="reserved">

<a name="slot1" style="background-color: green; width:100px; height:100px; border-top-right-radius:0px; border: 2px 
            solid Black;float:left; position:absolute; top:400px; left:441px;">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code is here

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("sample");




if(isset($_POST['occupied'])){
$query="UPDATE reservation SET status='occupied' where status='vacant'";
echo "<a style=background-color: red; width:100px; height:100px; border-top-right-radius:0px; border: 2px 
            solid Black;float:left; position:absolute; top:400px; left:441px;>";
}
?>
```

my problem is whenever i click the occupied button, the color of the box doesnt change from green to red, it only directs me to a blank page. help

Comment: As @jimp has pointed out, you need to put a `name` attribute on your HTML form elements. But hopefully you also know that when you click the button, the page redirects to `sample2.php` and all that exists on that page (based on your sample) is a link. No `<html>` tag, no `<body>` tag, no `<form>` element, no `<input>` elements...just a link, and that's it. Is that what you want?

Comment: The reason that the you see a blank page is that the Display Errors variable is set to 0. Set it to 1 using `set_ini('display_errors', 1)` , so you can track the error.!

Comment: @MiroMarkarian Or at least look at the PHP error log where the errors are likely already being reported.

Comment: @Travesty3 not exactly, my goal is whenever i clicked the occupied button, the box should turn red. in other words if the 'status' field in my reservation table is updated to occupied, the box should automatically turn into red. thanks.

Comment: @PauPauCaraan: Sounds like you should look into [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).

Comment: @Travesty3 oh okay. gonna study that AJAX. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<input type="submit" value="occupied" name="occupied">
<input type="submit" value="reserved" name="reserved">
```

Forms submit controls with a "name" and since those didn't have the name attribute, they aren't being submitted to your PHP script.

Read about [Successful Controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls) to learn more.

Comment: Older MS IE version do not transfer the nae of submit buttons…

Comment: I have never encountered that issue, that I'm aware of at least. How old do you mean?

Comment: I think it was MS IE 6 and 7; but on the other hand it's years ago, since I had this problem…

Answer (score 1):

you have to set together the id and the name into the form like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="sample2.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="occupied" id="occupied" name="occupied">
<input type="submit" value="reserved" id="reserved" name="reserved">

<a name="slot1" style="background-color: green; width:100px; height:100px; border-top-right-radius:0px; border: 2px 
            solid Black;float:left; position:absolute; top:400px; left:441px;"></a>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```